# GTK+ cross platform ubuntu theme

Tags: c, gtk, themes

I know that a cross platform GTK+ application will suit their GUI to the operating system they are (for example they will use ubuntu theme to fit in ubuntu and windows theme when used in windows).How can i make my application use the default ubuntu theme to the app even when its used at windows?

Comment: Not a good practice I think. A program should respect its environment :)

Comment: No. There isn't a "default Ubuntu theme" available on Windows. GTK doesn't pick a theme to go with the operating system; the operating system picks a theme for GTK.